# Probability that special subset is chosen?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

We are given $n$ different items and a knapsack with capacity $c$. Each item has weight $1$ and can only be packed once. We go blindly through the store and select each item with probability $p_i$ until we have exactly $c$ items selected.Note that $1 = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$. What is the probability that a special set $S$ of size $c$ is packed ?

I think it is $c\prod_{i \in S} p_i$, but it feels to easy. Can someone please tell me if this is correct or help me obtain the true solution?

Ok, so my solution is not correct. I am trying to understand how the correct formualar is derived. We set the set $S=\lbrace s_1, \dots, s_c \rbrace$ and denote by $\sigma$ all possible bijections between $\lbrace 1, \dots, c\rbrace$ and $S$. Denote by $X_i$ the value of the $i$-th chosen item.  Then we get

\begin{align*}Pr(S)&=\sum_{\sigma} Pr(X_1=s_{\sigma(1)} \land \dots \land X_c = s_{\sigma(c)}) \\&= \sum_{\sigma} Pr(X_1 =s_{\sigma(1)})Pr(X_2 = s_{\sigma(2)} \land \dots \land X_c = s_{\sigma(c)}|X_1 = s_{\sigma(1)})\\
&=\sum_{\sigma} p_1Pr(X_2 = s_{\sigma(2)} \land \dots \land X_c = s_{\sigma(c)}|X_1 = s_{\sigma(1)})\end{align*}

But then I get stuck. How do I compute the second term?

Comment: @saulspatz I don't think your statement is correct, since the $p_i$ are not necessary equal

Comment: @samabu Yes, my statement was wrong.  I misread the question.

Comment: ok, no worries :) but thanks neverthelessfor the input

Comment: If all the $p_i$ are equal to $1/n$, then the probability is $1/\binom nc$, whereas your formula gives $cn^{-c}$

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought it was too easy :D

Comment: do you have any idea how the true solution can be computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the subset $S$ of size $c$ is chosen is :
$$p(C) = \left(\prod_{i\in S}p_i\right)\sum_{\sigma}\left[\prod_{k=0}^{c-1}\frac{1}{1-\sum_{i=1}^kp_{\sigma(i)}}\right]$$

where the sum runs over all bijection $\sigma :\{1,\ldots,c\}\to S$

For a general distribution $(p_i)$, I don't think there is a way to simplify this further.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I have two questions and would be very glad, if you please could explain a little bit more. 1. With bijection do you mean all possible permutations? I do not really understand the sum. 2. How did you derive your formula? The first part (product over $p_i$ is clear, but what does the sum do?

Comment: The $\sigma$ aren't really permutation. Instead, they are one-ot-one and onto functions from $\{1,\ldots,c\}$ to $S$.

Comment: To derive the formula, you have to consider the events where the elements of $S$ are picked *in a specific order*. Computing their probabilities is not that hard. Then you sum over all the possible orders, which is what $\sum_\sigma$ is doing

Comment: Hello, thank you. But I am sorry, I still don't understand what it does. Assume we have a set $S=\lbrace{s_1, s_2\rbrace}$ and $c=2$, then what is the bijection doing? It one-to-one projects $\lbrace{1,2\rbrace}$ to $\lbrace{s_1, s_2\rbrace}$ So we would have a two bijections: One that maps 1 to $s_1$ and 2 to $s_2$ and one that maps it the other way around. But aren't these just permutations?

Comment: And the term in the sum does not depend on the bijection $\sigma$?

Comment: Well, permutations of $S = \{s_1,s_2\}$ are bijection from $S$ to $S$, so they are not exactly the same thing

Comment: I missed a $\sigma$ in the formula. It is corrected now.

Comment: Ah ok, so I think I do understand this part now. And the product in the some results from the probability that they are chosen in this specific order (if you consider the ocmment below e.g $Pr(Y=s_2|X=s_1)$. But how do you get the probability of this term

Comment: I edited the post, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'll do the case $c=2$.  I think this will show you the way to the general solution.  Let $X$ be a random variable whose value is the first item selected, and let $Y$ be a random variable whose value is the second item selected.  We seek
$$
\Pr(X=s_1\land Y=s_2)+\Pr(X=s_2\land Y=s_1)=\\\Pr(X=s_1)\Pr(Y=s_2|X=s_1)+
\Pr(X=s_2)\Pr(Y=s_1|X=s_2)\\
=p_1\frac{p_2}{1-p_1}+p_2\frac{p_1}{1-p_2}\\
=\prod_{i\in S}p_i\sum_{i\in S} \frac1{1-p_i}$$

As a sanity check, note that when $p_i\equiv\frac1n$, this gives $$\frac1{n^2}\cdot\frac2{1-1/n}=\frac2{n(n-1)}=\frac1{\binom{n}{2}}$$ as expected.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. Is it possible that there is a typo in the first line? That it should be $Pr(X=s_1 \land Y=s_2)+Pr(X=s_2 \land Y=s_1)$?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand how $Pr(Y=s_2|X=s_1)$ is computed. Why isn't it simply $p_2$?

Comment: There was a typo in the first line, thanks.  As to conditional probability, once $s_1$ has been chosen as the first pick, it cannot be chosen again.  The total probability of the items that can be selected is $1-p_1$, so to get a probability space, we divide the probability of each item by $1-p_1$.  Surely your textbook must discuss conditional probability.  Or, you can Google it.